# Add fake rows to a result of a query for not existing rows in the "in clause"

Tags: mysql, sql, select

sorry for the cryptic title, I will try to explain the problem with an example.
I'm using MySQL:
Let's say I have two simple tables testA and testB defined as follow:

```
create table testA(
pk_a int ,
des varchar(20)
);

create table testB(
pk_b int ,
des varchar(20),
fk_a int

);
```

And with these values:

```
insert into testA values (1,'AAAA');
insert into testA values (2,'BBBB');
insert into testA values (5,'XXXX');

insert into testB values (1,'some text 1',1);
insert into testB values (2,'some text 1',2);
insert into testB values (3,'some text 1',5);
```

Now if I execute a simple inner join like the following:

```
select * from testA a ,testB b
where a.pk_a=b.fk_a
and a.des in ('AAAA','XXXX','EEEE')
```

I get 2 rows:

```
pk_a | des  | pk_b | des       |    fk_a
-------------------------------------------

1     AAAA    1     some text 1      1
5     XXXX    3     some text 1      5
```

I would like to get even the row for 'EEEE' (value present in the in clause but not in testA table ) with null values so :

```
pk_a | des  | pk_b | des       |    fk_a
-------------------------------------------

1     AAAA    1     some text 1      1
5     XXXX    3     some text 1      5
null  EEEE    null  null             null
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? maybe with a union clause?
Take into account that the values in the "in clause" are variable and they are passed by a Java application.

Any suggestions will be appreciate.
(you can find the SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/faae08/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One dirty (neat?) trick is to query all these values as literals and left join that result to the existing query:

```
SELECT    a.*, b.*
FROM      (SELECT 'AAAA' AS des
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'XXXX'
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT 'EEEE') v
LEFT JOIN testA a ON v.des = a.des
LEFT JOIN testB b ON a.pk_a = b.fk_a
```

Comment: Hi Mureinik,, thak you for your answer, but if I copy-paste your query in the SQLFiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/faae08/1) I get exactly the same result of the inner join (2 rows), did I miss something?

Comment: @navy1978 my bad - the second join should have also been a `left join` - see my edited answer.

Comment: using the modified answer I get the extra row but with all NULL, the column 'a.des' instead of 'EEEE' contains NULL

Comment: Your solution is working adding in the first select v.* . Like that an extra column is added to the result with all the values even the 'EEEE' one. This is not exactly what I was looking for, but for the moment is a possible solution, changing the java code a little bit... Thank you ;)

Comment: Sorry on a second thought I think is the correct answer, I ‘m going to accept this... thank you again ;)